# Save file in iCloud Drive Documents (user Access)

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, icloud-drive

I want to save a PDF file in the iCloud Drive. The user should have access to the file over his iCloud Drive App.

At the moment I can save a file in the iCloud Drive but it is in a hidden directory.

```
struct DocumentsDirectory {
    static let localDocumentsURL: NSURL? =  FileManager.default.urls(for:     FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in:     .userDomainMask).last! as NSURL
    static var url: NSURL? =   FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)! as NSURL
    static let iCloudDocumentsURL: NSURL? = url?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")! as! NSURL
}
```

With this code I get the hidden directory in the iCloud Drive (which is specific to my app).

Now my question is: can I save the file in the standard documents directory in the iCloud Drive?  Or can I create a folder for the documents from my app, which the user can see?

Comment: actually I have made it work. The only way I see to go is to use the UIDocumentPickerViewController. If you know a better solution where you don't need the Picker I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try saving the file under the 'Documents' directory, this ensure the file is saved under the users public directory and is visible in the iCloud app as well.

```
func setupiCloudDriveForFileExport() {

    if let iCloudDocumentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents") {
        if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(iCloudDocumentsURL.path!, isDirectory: nil)) {
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(iCloudDocumentsURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code checks for the existance of the Documents directory on iCloud and if not creates a new one.